# Loading iOS Bundle on real device

Tags: ios, xcode

I've a plugin bundle that should be loaded in my app.
When I run the app on iOS simulator, the bundle is loaded correctly, but when I recompile the project in order to run the app on my real device, I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "dlopen_preflight(/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35F71C99-1072-4772-8BFB-3CB8C034A935/Documents/grandmaAdapter.bundle/grandmaAdapter): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35F71C99-1072-4772-8BFB-3CB8C034A935/Documents/grandmaAdapter.bundle/grandmaAdapter: mmap() error 1 at address=0x022CF000, size=0x00008000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35F71C99-1072-4772-8BFB-3CB8C034A935/Documents/grandmaAdapter.bundle/grandmaAdapter" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35F71C99-1072-4772-8BFB-3CB8C034A935/Documents/grandmaAdapter.bundle/grandmaAdapter, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “grandmaAdapter” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35F71C99-1072-4772-8BFB-3CB8C034A935/Documents/grandmaAdapter.bundle/grandmaAdapter): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35F71C99-1072-4772-8BFB-3CB8C034A935/Documents/grandmaAdapter.bundle/grandmaAdapter: mmap() error 1 at address=0x022CF000, size=0x00008000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35F71C99-1072-4772-8BFB-3CB8C034A935/Documents/grandmaAdapter.bundle/grandmaAdapter, NSBundlePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35F71C99-1072-4772-8BFB-3CB8C034A935/Documents/grandmaAdapter.bundle}
```

Basically what I do is:

-Defining filepath in document directory

```
NSString *bundleName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.bundle", bundle];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:bundleName];
```

-And then loading the bundle

```
NSBundle *plugin = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:filePath];

NSError *err;
if(![plugin loadAndReturnError:&err]) {
    // err contains error info
} else {
    // bundle loaded properly

}
```

And here I've got the error above

Could someone help me? Thanks

**SOLVED**

The error was related to the lack of code signature.
As reported in this post: http://ddeville.me/2014/04/dynamic-linking/
the plugin needs to be signed in order to be loaded on real devices, with the following command:

```
codesign --sign "iPhone Developer" --force --verbose=4 myPluginName.plugin
```

Comment: How did you load the bundle into the Simulator? If programmatically, please show your code.

Comment: I've edited with my code

Comment: Maybe the problem could be related to directory access permission issues?(on real device). Even though the message reports bundle damaged or missing data..

Comment: It is not related to permission issues--I ran into the same error when I tried this. I'm not in front of my computer now, but I will look at my code this evening, and give you a definitive answer!

Comment: Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, just wanted to let you know I'm writing up an answer now...

Answer (score 0):

Your bundle-loading code looks good, until `loadAndReturnError:`. I came across this same error, when figuring out how to load bundles.

I know this sounds counter-intuitive, but you don't need to call that method. Instead, try the approach below.

I hope this helps! If you still get an error, then the issue might be with the way you've created your bundle.

```
UIView *resourceView = nil;

NSBundle *resourceBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:resourcePath];

@try {
    //Try to load the NIB from the given bundle
    resourceView = [[resourceBundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:owner options:nil] lastObject];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    //do nothing - will search in main bundle
}

//If loading from the given bundle failed, try loading from the main bundle
if (!resourceView) {
    NSBundle *resourceBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    @try {
        resourceView = [[resourceBundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:owner options:nil] lastObject];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        //do nothing - will return nil, indicating an error occurred
    }
}

return resourceView;
```

**Word of Caution**

Before going down this path, it is important to note that the only reason that you really need to create a bundle is to add XIB files. For any other assets, such as images, audio or video files, it suffices (and is much more straightforward) to simply zip up the files and download them from a server location to be unzipped into your documents directory.

If you ever need to update assets that are used by a XIB, then it is best to load those assets programmatically, instead of setting them in the XIB (or in addition to setting defaults in the XIB). This way, you can be freed from using the bundle approach, and instead use a zipped archive as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Sheamus but this is not what I need.. I'm developing an app that downloads a plugin from a remote server and loads the code at runtime..

Comment: @davideb How did you create the Bundle?

Comment: Creating a Bundle project (extension .plugin) and changing the Base SDK to Latest iOS

Comment: Anyway the strange thing is that the same code works fine on simulator, whereas seems to lack resources (dependencies?) on my real device..

Comment: @davideb Ah, I see. I didn't have to do that. I assume it's because I didn't have an executable in my bundle, only assets.